# slowly updating global window side input with rate configurable by pipeline option

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to use a [slowly updating global window side inputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/#slowly-updating-global-window-side-inputs) to periodically refresh some configuration data in my pipeline

```
p.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(5L)))
```

I would like the refresh period to be configurable via a pipeline option. I tried using a `ValueProvider<Long> refreshSeconds`, but beam tells me "Value only available at runtime, but accessed from a non-runtime context".

```
p.apply(GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(refreshSeconds.get())))
```

Is there a way to make this work?